# every time i start my computer blue screen of death shows up and restarts it

Tags: windows-10, boot, login

every time i start my computer blue screen of death shows up and restarts it. This means I am unable to use my computer. I tried resetting windows but I didn't have the permissions. What happens is I turn on my computer and then it gets the blue screen of death and then restarts infinately. Before this started happening I reinstalled visual studio and it asked me to restart and then I got this bad blue screen situation. Please help. Anything is deeply appreciated.

Comment: After the third try it should come up in recovery mode. At this time you should be able to select "fix startup problems" (paraphrasing).

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well using the windows installation media on the USB to access the advanced repair options with administrator permissions but it doesn't fix it

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-troubleshoot-blue-screen-errors-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Try repetitively tapping the F8 key while windows is starting up. This should give you some recovery options if they don't show up automatically after several bluescreens.

If startup recovery doesn't work, select booting into safe mode. If it boots successfully into safe mode, uninstall Visual Studio.

If you can't get the recovery options to show up you can use a different computer and an empty usb drive to create a recovery tool as instructed here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-recovery-drive-abb4691b-5324-6d4a-8766-73fab304c246

You can then plug that usb into the computer with a problem, boot into the usb, and follow the instructions. Leave a comment if you need help booting into a usb.

Comment: I fixed it by using a windows installation media to restore a previous windows version multiple times but then the restore version stopped appearing and now I can't fix it anymore.

Comment: How can I boot my computer in safe mode?

Comment: I deleted visual studio but the BSOD reboot loop is still happening